# como guardar el resultado de una subconsulta en mysql para poder compararlo

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta de la tabla usuarios. Entre sus campos tengo un campo llamado "fechadenacimiento", a través de una subconsulta obtengo la edad y lo muestro en los resultados. Nótese que este valor no existe en la tabla lo obtengo al vuelo, sin embargo necesito poder guardarlo (o setearlo) para poder  hacer filtros tipo:

```
 where edad > 18 || edad < 22
```

Esta es mi consulta.

```
select u.id, u.nombre, u.rfc as cu, u.nombre as estado, u.categoria, u.fnacimiento, YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.fnacimiento) as edad
from usuarios as u
```

Necesito hacer algo del tipo:

```
select u.id, u.nombre, u.rfc as cu, u.nombre as estado, u.categoria, u.fnacimiento, YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.fnacimiento) as edad
from usuarios as u where edad > 18 && <30
```

¿Esto es posible?

Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano edad no es un campo de su tabla si no un alias

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿seguro? Yo se que antiguamente no se podia.

Comment: Exacto al no ser campo de la tabla no lo puedo comprar, me marca un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Oh sí, pues fíjate que pensé que sí se podía :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza la misma función en el where con un `BETWEEN`

```
select u.id, u.nombre, u.rfc as cu, u.nombre as estado, u.categoria, u.fnacimiento, YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.fnacimiento) as edad
from usuarios as u where YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.fnacimiento) BETWEEN 19 AND 29
```

Comment: ojo que el between es inclusivo y la consulta del OP es excluyente con los límites inferior y superior

Comment: Editado, gracias @amenadiel

Comment: De nada colega, para eso estamos

Comment: Te agradezco bastante. Marco como respuesta correcta porque fue el primero en proporcionarla y se adapta justo a lo que necesito, sin más ni menos. Sin embargo, cabe recalcar que las otras respuestas también son opciones válidas. Agradezco infinitamente tu ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma de hacerlo sería usando `HAVING`, del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.nombre, 
    u.rfc cu, 
    u.nombre estado, 
    u.categoria, 
    u.fnacimiento, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, u.fnacimiento, CURDATE()) edad
FROM usuarios u 
HAVING edad BETWEEN 18 AND 30;
```

- Recomiendo que uses un estilo más SQL, con `BETWEEN`.
- El uso de [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) proporcionará datos más precisos, sobre todo cuando la hora importe. Si naciste el día `X` a la hora `Y`, hasta la hora `Y` no has cumplido años :)

---

#### Código de prueba

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/CSOSJ93155)**</kbd>

Comment: What sorcery is this!!?? Nunca había visto usar un having sin un group.

Comment: @amenadiel lo estás viendo ante tus propios ojos :) [For more info](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57445).

Comment: Tiene mucho sentido. Justo mañana tengo un meetup con Álvaro Herrera (desarrollador de PostgreSQL, inventor de los índices BRIN y los background workers) y en PG los background workers son los que apoyan la fase de agregación

Answer (score 2):

yo veo dos maneras (hay más en realidad pero son más enrevesadas)

**Una: pon la misma fórmula en el WHERE**

```
select u.id, u.nombre, u.rfc as cu, u.nombre as estado, u.categoria, u.fnacimiento, YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.fnacimiento) as edad
from usuarios as u
where ( YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.fnacimiento) ) between 19 AND 29
```

Nótese que usé 19 y 29 porque estás usando una condición que no incluye 18 ni 30.

**Dos: envuelve toda la consulta principal como subconsulta**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select u.id, u.nombre, u.rfc as cu, u.nombre as estado, u.categoria, u.fnacimiento, YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.fnacimiento) as edad
from usuarios as u) aux
WHERE edad>18 AND edad<30
```

Otra alternativa sería por ejemplo declarar una variable e irla actualizando en cada registro al valor de la edad.

Answer (score 2):

Trato de contestar desde la app lamento sino está identado correctamente, pero intenta esto

```
select obj1.*
    from (


select u.id, u.nombre, u.rfc as cu, u.nombre as estado, u.categoria, u.fnacimiento, YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.fnacimiento) as edad from usuarios as u

    )obj1
    Where obj1.edad >18 AND obj1.edad<30
```